# My MDFloatLayout and its properties isnt displaying on the screen

Tags: python, canvas, kivy, kivymd

I was trying to designing a homes creen with canvas in kivyMD and I had succeeded to create ellipses up and down, but now I keep trying to display other contents on the screen but nothing is displayed no matter what position I put it in.  My kv code is down below...

```
Template = '''
MDFloatLayout:
    MDFloatLayout:
        
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0,'center_y': 1.2}
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: (132/255, 0, 117/255, 0)
            Ellipse:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size[0]*2, self.size[0]/1.75
                source: "test.jpg"


    #This MDLabel is one of the contents not being displayed
    MDLabel:
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .23, 'center_y':2.9}
        text: '568 followers'
        bold: True

    MDFloatLayout:
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0, 'center_y':0}
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: (223/255, 237/255, 240/255, 0)
            Ellipse:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size[0]*2, self.size[0]* 1.95

#This FloatLayout below isnt being displayed too
    MDFloatLayout:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: dp(200), dp(240)
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .3, 'center_y':.3}
        radius: [dp(20)]*4
        md_bg_color: 250/255, 250/255, 250/255, 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of your widgets in the `kv` you posted fill the entire screen, hiding anything behind them. Note that the default `size_hint` is `(1,1)`. Also, the `pos_hint` for the `MDLabel`:

```
pos_hint: {'center_x': .23, 'center_y':2.9}
```

sets the center of the `MDLabel` well beyond the top of the display.

Try changing `size_hint` from the default and adjusting `pos_hint`. Not knowing what your goal is, I have modified your `kv` just to make everything visible:

```
MDFloatLayout:
    MDFloatLayout:

        pos_hint: {'center_x':0,'center_y': 1.2}
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: (132/255, 0, 117/255, 0)
            Ellipse:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size[0]*2, self.size[0]/1.75
                source: "test.jpg"


    #This MDLabel is one of the contents not being displayed
    MDLabel:
        pos_hint: {'right': 1, 'y':0}
        size_hint: 0.2, 0.2
        text: '568 followers'
        bold: True

    MDFloatLayout:
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0, 'center_y':0}
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.5
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: (223/255, 237/255, 240/255, 0)
            Ellipse:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size[0]*2, self.size[0]* 1.95

#This FloatLayout below isnt being displayed too
    MDFloatLayout:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: dp(200), dp(240)
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .3, 'center_y':.3}
        radius: [dp(20)]*4
        md_bg_color: 250/255, 250/255, 250/255, 0
```